# casting to an unknown type reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, types

the problem I am currently having is that I am trying to cast to an unknown type and I receive this message from the following code:

> The type or namespace name 'thistype' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
String thistype = null;

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{

    thistype =  typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i].ToString()).PropertyType.Name; 
    typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i].ToString()).SetValue(currentSearch,(thistype)properties[i], null);

}
```

If you need any more information just ask and any help would be appreciated, thanks.
- Chris

Comment: Why bother casting at all? `SetValue` takes an `object`. Casting is fundamentally about types that you know *at compile-time*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to cast at all, assuming the value of `properties[i]` is already *actually* the right type:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i].ToString())
                                  .SetValue(currentSearch, properties[i], null);
}
```

If you were trying to invoke a user-defined conversion (e.g. from `XElement` to `String`) then that's a lot more complicated.

Comment: the problem is that items[i] relates to a variety of fields eg ID and Name and Properties needs to be cast as an int for the ID field or it will fall over with the following exception:
Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'.

Comment: @Chris: You wouldn't be able to *cast* from a `string` to an `int?` anyway. It sounds like you need to perform appropriate conversions, e.g. using `int.Parse`. Don't focus on casting - that's not the problem. You need to focus on making sure that the value you're trying to specify is of the right execution-time type.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep looking into it, cheers for the help though appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

For any future reference, this is the (very sloppy) way of doing what I was trying to do, I will be improving on this but I thought I should leave this here for anyone else.

```
            thistype =  typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i].ToString()).PropertyType.FullName;

            if (thistype == "System.String")
            {
                 typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i]).SetValue(currentSearch, properties[i], null);
            }
            else if (thistype == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
            {

                long number = Int64.Parse(properties[i]);
                typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i]).SetValue(currentSearch, number, null);

            }
            else if (thistype == "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]")
            {

                int number = Int32.Parse(properties[i]);
                typeof(BugManagerQueryOptions).GetProperty(items[i]).SetValue(currentSearch, number, null);

            }
```

Comment: Use `typeof(string)` etc instead of comparing names.